# How do I test a web application's file upload function using jMeter?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

My web application has a function to upload files to the server. How do I test the performance of this using jMeter?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use POST method of [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) Sampler with "Use multipart/form-data" box checked and providing following options:

- Full path to file for upload
- Valid `Parameter Name` (see relevant `<input type="file">` value in page code or record your upload via [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder)
- Specify correct `MIME Type`

See [Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) guide for more details.